# MultiThreading, java Main() and Video Play

Tags: java, multithreading

I use Xuggler to display a video.

I use two threads, one for the audio, and one for the video.

The problem i have is when i reach a CPU use of about 30% the video starts to stutter, and is not smooth anymore.

But if i run the video from the Main() function, the video is smooth. The thing is that i don't know how to play the video on the main Thread. When i start the PlayVideo function from a subclass, it blocks the system.

Any help is welcome.

Jeff

Comment: ACCEPTANCE IS NO SO GOOD BRUTHER

Comment: Like here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037321/no-repaint-while-resizing-when-using-setpaintgradient

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't know i had to accept answers. Will do in the future, thanks. (now all you have to do is to answer to my question so i can accept your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i found a solution

It's dirty as hell but it works.

Actually i start the playing of the video in the main thread at the far en of main() (so that it doesn't blocks the GUI components) and i enter an infinite loop and i get out of this loop when i want to read the video.

The main thread has a priority far superior to any other thread that's why my video is smooth on the main thread.

Here it is i hope i helped people in need like i was.